# Create app that can send data from computer to Android app

Tags: android

I want host(my PC) that can send data through internet to many clients(Android phones with my app). The thing that I would need to know is, what is the things that needed? Is this possible? I don't want it to restricted to only Local Area Network.

At this moment, I know that to develop an Android app will need language like Eclipse, C++ and Java.

Sorry, please don't close my question, I just want to know whether we can send data from our PC to Android apps or not, cause I'm going to create such app for my school project.

Comment: First of all, make a base study. - [Toutorial-Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/android.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the apps run on hosts within the same network, then you can use direct socket communication. Just look for [`java socket programming`](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=yy9ZUqn_NMnc4QTZ_IG4Bw#q=java%20socket%20programming) in java and in [`android`](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=yy9ZUqn_NMnc4QTZ_IG4Bw#q=android%20socket%20programming). I would expect however to base on the same code.

You need to see who is the server (who listens for data) and the who is the client (who sends data).

Other mean would be to host a web server on your PC and have the client to make some http requests to it. It depends on your use case.

Comment: My case would be the second one, my PC would be the host and Android phones would be the clients. I would like to have one way connection which is data send from one host to many clients. How can I make my PC as host in this case?